# How to find the number of `NA` values in column names containing specific string and display number of `NA` values of each column separately?

Tags: r

Let's say I have a bunch of columns, and many of them contain "start_time" in their column names. How do I count the number of `NA` values in each of those columns and display the answer separately (NOT as a sum of all `NA` values found).

example output:

```
abc_start_time
## 5

xyz_start_time
## 1

ggg_start_time_end
## 0
```

or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```r
lapply(df[grep("start_time", names(df))], function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
#> $abc_start_time
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $def_start_time
#> [1] 2
```

---

**Data used**

```r
df <- data.frame(abc_start_time = c(NA, 1, 2),
                 def_start_time = c(NA, NA, 3),
                 abc_end_time = c(NA, 2, 2))
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `colSums()` to sum the TRUE/FALSE with `grep()` to identify all the desired columns:

```
colSums(is.na(df[grep("start_time", names(df))]))

#     abc_start_time     xyz_start_time ggg_start_time_end 
#                 5                  2                  0
```

The part `is.na(df[grep("start_time", names(df))]` will return a boolean matrix (TRUE/FALSE) of all the columns with "starts_with" in the name. The `colSums()` part will sum all the `TRUE` as 1 and `FALSE` as 0 by column.
Data

```
df <- data.frame(abc_start_time = seq.Date(as.Date("2023/01/01"), as.Date("2023/01/30"), by = "day"),
                 xyz_start_time = seq.Date(as.Date("2023/01/01"), as.Date("2023/01/30"), by = "day"),
                 ggg_start_time_end = seq.Date(as.Date("2023/01/01"), as.Date("2023/01/30"), by = "day"),
                 another_column = seq.Date(as.Date("2023/01/01"), as.Date("2023/01/30"), by = "day"))
df[c(1,3,5:7), 1] <- NA
df[c(6,7), 2] <- NA
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  summarise(across(contains('start_time'), ~ sum(is.na(.x))))
 abc_start_time def_start_time
1              1              2
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `map_df()` from `purrr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  select(contains("start_time")) %>% 
  map_df(~sum(is.na(.)))
```

```
  abc_start_time def_start_time
           <int>          <int>
1              1              2
```